# Template Dialogue Box not showing up when trying to create a new file in a Xcode Workspace

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, file, xcode10

When I right click to add a new file (or do File -> New -> File), I don't get a dialogue box asking me which Template I want to use. It just creates a blank file like this:

[image]

I tried renaming it to a .swift file and adding in all the necessary code to start off, but two things happen:

1. First, the autocomplete function is one step behind. So when I've already typed `import UIKit` and moved on, it starts trying to autocomplete `UIKit`. And when I've already typed `class className: UICollectionViewController {
   }` and moved on, it starts trying to autcomplete `UICollectionViewController`
2. After I manually type in the bare minimum needed to make a swift file into a UICollectionViewController with a colored background, I can't reference it in my other files.

I can only assume this is because of the lack of a template dialogue box, but maybe I'm wrong. Is there any way to toggle this template dialogue box on or off?

This problem is only happening with this particular project since I updated to Xcode 10.1

I can't seem to find anyone else online who's already had this issue. The only similar questions I found online were referring to creating reference folders rather than groups. I didn't find anything regarding the file template dialogue box not showing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this and I'll post the answer in case anyone else comes across this problem.

It was tedious, but I:

- Created a new project
- Initialized my podfile, added what was in the previous one, and installed it
- Opened up the new workspace
- Added each file one by one

Maybe there's an easier/quicker way to do it, but after looking through all the settings and not finding anything, I ended up doing this and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Check that in the left hand pane displaying your project structure you are adding the new file to a folder which comes under your application (identified by a blue Xcode application icon) instead of a general folder as your top level (identified by a blue folder icon). [I can't add images yet so please see link.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8qm3.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the left sidebar Navigator (folder icon), select any item except for a Folder Reference (blue folder icon). Choose New > File... (note the ... is present to indicate you'll get a dialog).

When a Folder Reference was last selected (even if the sidebar is hidden), New > "File..." changes to "File" and the menu item creates a file inside the folder as you described.

You can also relaunch Xcode, which defaults to the File... mode on launch, but it is not necessary, just select something that's not a blue folder as described above.